# Site is not accessible after deploying to the live server with docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ubuntu-20.04, docker-networking

There is a web application, which is placed within a docker container. When I start the docker container using the docker compose locally - everything works fine. However, after deploying it to the live server, it returns the '**ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT**' error. Sometimes there is another error: '**ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED**' I can't understand why that happens. As I have said, it works perfect locally after starting the docker container. I have checked two things on the server:

1. the ubuntu firewall is inactive on the live server
2. when I start the docker container, the specific port that I'm using is shown as listening (the web application is using the 8181 port):

`sudo netstat -ntlp`

`tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8181            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1391364/docker-prox`

when I stop the web application docker container - the record above disappears, which means that it is working as intended.

why does the same docker container - works fine locally, however doesn't work when deployed to the live server?

I'm not sure whether it is important, the live server version is: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-78-generic aarch64)

Comment: does the host hosting the live server allow traffic through port 8181?

Comment: yeah, exactly that was the reason. Already resolved. Thanks man!